# Best way to write CTAS with outer joins in query

Tags: oracle12c

am trying to create a table using ctas, below is my query which is taking 24 mins..is there any way i can improve my query?

```
create table CHUB1
nologging
parallel
as          
select  /*+ PARALLEL */ D.CUSt_ID,
                D.FIRST_NM,
                D.MIDDLE_NM
          from  Chub_DETAIL_OT  D,--29 m records
                Chub_ADDR_OT A,--28 m records
                CHUB_PHONES P,--22 m records
                CHUB_EMAILS E --5 m records
         where  1=1
           and  A.CUSTOMER_ID(+) = D.CUSTOMER_ID
           and  P.CUSTOMER_ID(+) = D.CUSTOMER_ID
           and  E.CUSTOMER_ID(+) = D.CUSTOMER_ID;
```

Database : Oracle 12c,
Please let me know if you need further details. thank you!

Comment: Is there something missing from the column list? Currently you are selecting columns solely from `chub_DETAIL_OT`. This means two things: absence of records in `Chub_ADDR_OT`, `CHUB_PHONES`, and `CHUB_EMAILS` will not keep records from appearing, because of the outer join; and presence of multiple matching records for same `CUSTOMER_ID` in any of the three tables will cause duplicate rows in output. It seems like there is currently no need at all for the three outer-joined tables.